# Unity2D | If click go up on y-axis, else pingpong movement on a x-axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, translate

I have a script which is kind of work: When I click the Player starts going up and when I release, the Player start doing the Pingpong movement. The problem is when I release the mouse button, the player position is changing in the x-axis every time. It looks like the pingpong movement and never stops.  When it stops going up, join back where it should to be. I hope its understandable.

Heres my script:

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        float translation = 6f;
        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(0, translation, 0);
    } 
    else
    {
        float min = -2.3f;
        float max = +2.3f;
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 6, max - min) + min, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sory but I don't think I understood you correctly.
But I noticed two things that might be troublesome.
First)
In your `if` statement, you put `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` which will be true when mouse button is pressed. This makes your `else` triger when the button is not pressed. 
You mentioned in your post that you want that ping pong move when button is released, and 'on release' is not the same thing as 'not pressed'.
Maybe you wanted your `else` statement to triger on button release, not on button not pressed. Because, in its current form, the ping pong movement will be active as long as you don't press the mouse button again.

Anyway
second thing.
Not sure in which axis you wanted the ping pong movement to happen.
because, according to documentation, 
this line of code 
`transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 6, max - min) + min, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

will make ping pong movement in X axis.

[Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) to the documentation . You need to change this line to make a ping pong move in other axis.

Comment: also, if it doesn't solve your problems.
Try removing ```max - min) + min``` from this part from ```transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 6, max - min) + min, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);``` as for some reasons that I can't clarify, it looks suspicious to me ;p

Comment: Thank you for answering. I solved. My problem was with this line and i replaced it with a transform.translate: transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 6, max - min) + min, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);